# C# - Using multiple data calls in an ASP.NET MVC 3 view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET MVC 3 with razor and so far getting the hang of it.

one thing I'm stuck on is trying to getting multiple data calls to work.

a background to what I'm doing. I have a page that will show info about a project(which i got working) but i also want to show the progress of that project(which is another data call). I can't get the progress data to show. i tried using viewbag, but got:

> System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String]

I'm using stored procedures with the Entity Framework.

I appreciate the help guys.

EDIT:

Here is a rough example of my problem:

```
private SDMPREntities _db = new SDMPREntities();
public ActionResult Details(int id) { 
ViewData.Model = _db.ViewProjectDetails(id).ToList();
ViewBag.Progress = _db.ProjectProgress();
return View();
}
```

EDIT2:

@James D'Angelo, yes in the view. Heres the razor code:

```
@model IEnumerable<DeveloperManagerSharp.Models.Projects>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Project Details";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/project-ui.cshtml";
}

<div class="post">
<h3 class="title">
    Project Details</h3>
<div class="entry">
    <h4>
        Select a Project</h4>
    <p>
        Select a project below to see their progress or to update any of their properties.</p>
</div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
{    
<div class="post">
    <h3 class="title">@item.project_name (@item.project_version) @ViewBag.Progress%</h3>
    <div class="meta">
        <div class="posted">
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to Projects", "Index")
        </div>
        @if (@item.project_completed == "1") {
            <div class="date">
                Project is Completed.
            </div>
            } else {
            <div class="date">
                Project is Under Work.
            </div>       
            }
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        @if(@item.project_status == "0")
            {
            <span>Status: Planning</span><br />
            }
            else if(@item.project_status == "1")
            {
            <span>Status: Alpha</span><br />
            }
            else if(@item.project_status == "2")
            {
            <span>Status: Beta</span><br />
            }
            else if(@item.project_status == "3")
            {
            <span>Status: Release Candiate</span><br />
            }
            else if(@item.project_status == "4")
            {
            <span>Status: Active</span><br />
            }
            else if(@item.project_status == "5")
            {
            <span>Status: Maure</span><br />
            }
            else if(@item.project_status == "6")
            {
            <span>Status: Discontinued</span><br />
            }
        Starts: @item.project_sdate<br />
        Ends: @item.project_edate<br />
        <em>@item.project_desc</em>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you say is not working?

Comment: Sure.

private SDMPREntities _db = new SDMPREntities();
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
   // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database

   ViewData.Model = _db.ViewProjectDetails(id).ToList();
   ViewBag.Progress = _db.ProjectProgress();
   return View();
        }

Comment: now its possible my entity function is wrong, which i have it returning as decimal since it only returns a decimal amount.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Where are you getting "System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String]"?  In the view?  If so, can you post the Razor as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call

```
_db.ProjectProgress();
```

Is most likely returning an ObjectResult, which represents a collection of items.

So when you tried to display it in the view with

```
@ViewBag.Progress
```

ToString() is being called, which simply prints out the type.

To get around this, you want to fetch a specific result from the set. Without knowing your data structure I can only hazard a guess, e.g.

```
_db.ProjectProgress().Single(p=>p.ProjectId == id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following.

**Data Layer Code**

```
 public class ProjectDetailManager 
 {   
   public static List<ViewProjectDetail> GetProjectDetailById(int id)    
   {
       using(var dbContext = new SDMPREntities())
       {
          return dbContext.ViewProjectDetails(id).ToList();
       }    
    }

    public static ProjectProgress GetProjectProgress(int id)    
    {
       using(var dbContext = new SDMPREntities())
       {
          return dbContext.ProjectProgress().Where(x=>x.ProjectId ==id).FirstOrDefault();
       }    
    }

 }
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) 
{
  ViewData.Model = ProjectDetailManager.GetProjectDetailById(id); 
   ViewBag.Progress = ProjectDetailManager.GetProjectProgress(id);
   return View();    
}
```

**View Code**

```
     @model IEnumerable<ViewProjectDetail> 
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Project Details";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SiteContent.cshtml";
     }
@// not sure what your object look like but here an example 
    <h1>Project Status: @(ViewBag.Progress != null ? ViewBag.Progress.Status : string.Empty)</h1>

       @foreach(var item in Model) 
       {     
          //format display whatever 
       }
```